# iOS - core data - UITableView - update calculated value - NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, transient, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**Overview**

- I have an iOS project using core data (`NSFetchedResultsController`) and table view. I have a field called "joingDate".
- I have a set of labels on the table view cell to represent the data.
- If the joiningDate is today / tomorrow, then I would like to display as "today" or "tomorrow" instead of specifying the actual date.
- I was just thinking, I would check for the lastCheckedDate (last time when the date was checked) and if it over a day, then I would have to update all those labels in the rows which have a joining date and "today" or "tomorrow".
- In the database the "JoiningDate" would be stored as a Date, only the label needs to display "today" / "tomorrow" / date in a specific format.

I have implemented, the following method, where the label "joingDateComments" is updated based on it's current date.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**Question**

Note - I am using `NSFetchedResultsController`

1. what is the best approach to update all those rows labels which have a `joiningDate` as today / tomorrow ?
2. Should I reload all the records in the table ? (but this would only affect a few rows.)
3. Should I loop through all indexes and check and update. I am not sure this would work because I am using `NSFetchedResultsController`.
4. Should I use transient data, so that I can just query the database and get the records which have a "JoingDate" as today / tomorrow and update the transient field `JoingDateComments`, so that the those records would automatically be refreshed by the NSFetchedResultsController

**Answer:**

Pls go through Andrew's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user1046037,

This really isn't a Core Data question but a UITableView question. Most everything is handled in the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. There you will choose how you represent the cell. The other place will be when the `NSFetchedResultsController` calls you with the changed objects. (The standard Core Data table view controller writes this boiler plate for you.) In other words you should not have to loop over all of your objects. If you want finer grain control of when these cells are updated, you can listen for the did save notification. Then query the tableView for the array of visible cells. The cell index paths can then be used with to update the cell contents.

Andrew

Comment: thanks Andrew, what you said makes sense. The only problem I had was that "joiningDate" is stored in the database and when I want to display the cell I check if it yesterday / today / tomorrow and provide the appropriate comments, but the current date keeps changing, and at some point, it needs to be refreshed. Now I do a house keeping task to check the records that need to be updated by querying the database when the app is launched / comes to this screen from a different screen. I have a separate field in the database to represent the type of date (today / tomorrow / yesterday)

Comment: user1046037, Again this has nothing to do with Core Data. It has everything to do with finding the visible table view cells and updating the day designator. Why are you keeping the format of your date string, today/tomorrow/yesterday, in your model? Comparisons against NSDate.date are all you need. You know, MVC and all that... I think you are making this problem harder than it needs to be. BTW, iOS will send you a notification when there has been a significant time change. You can use this to trigger your UI update. Andrew

Comment: thanks Andrew, If i don't store in the database, how would I know which are the cells which are displaying the wrong string. If don't store it the database then I have to do a complete reload of all the data. So now I store which records have the label as "yesterday" / "today" / "tomorrow", so that i can query them and update them when a day has passed along with the records which fall between yesterday and day after tomorrow. With respect to notifications. Every app has only 64 slots and in most cases o hit the limit, so i don't want to use notification.

Comment: user1046037, you are dealing with a comparatively trivial number of items, the ones visible in the table view. Just update them all. You are wrong about the 64 entry limit in NSNotificationCenter. Use NSNotificationCenter. Andrew

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I have a question about NSNotificationCenter, would you know what I should subscribe to, so that I get notifications when the system date changes (i mean every day at 12:00 midnight).

Comment: user1046037, these are notifications from `UIApplication`. The one you want is: `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`. I would encourage you to read the docs about the Cocoa Touch app architecture. In any event, as you appear to be a new member of the Stack Overflow community and if this conversation has proved helpful, please check the check mark by my answer. Andrew